# Insert separator in Python input() function

Tags: python, input, separator

I'm looking for a way to insert separator in the `input()` function.

To be clear, my script asks the user to input a timeout in H:MM:SS, and I'd like Python to insert `:` by himself.
So if the user types "14250", I want the terminal to display 1:42:50 (during the input, not after pressing ENTER).

Is it possible in Python?

Comment: Probably not with `input`, maybe by reading and echoing individual characters, or using `curses`

Comment: Pure Python can't see what's being typed until the user submits the input, so you'll have to use something OS-specific, like curses.

Comment: Alright I'll look that way, thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version for Linux. It is based on and very similar to the [version by anurag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65737121/1639625), but Linux's `getch` modules does not know `getwch` and `putwch`, so those have to be substituted.

```
from getch import getche as getc

def gettime():
    timestr = ''
    print('Enter time in 24-hr format (hh:mm:ss): ', end='', flush=True)
    for i in range(6):
        timestr += getc()  # get and echo character
        if i in (1, 3):    # add ":" after 2nd and 4th digit
            print(":", end="", flush=True)
            timestr += ':'
    print()                # complete the line
    return timestr

time = gettime()
print("The time is", time)
```

Sample output:

```
Enter time in 24-hr format (hh:mm:ss): 12:34:56
The time is 12:34:56
```

I *think* this would also work on Windows with `from msvcrt import getwche as getc` but I can not test this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to achieve the result (*to some extent*), tested on Windows 10, Python 3.7:

```py
import msvcrt as osch

def main():
    timestr = ''
    print('Enter time in 24-hr format (hh:mm:ss): ', end='', flush=True)
    for i in range(6):
        ch = osch.getwch()
        
        if i!=0 and i%2==0:
            osch.putwch(':')
            timestr += ':'
        osch.putwch(ch)
        timestr += ch
    return timestr


if __name__ == "__main__":
    res = main()
    print('\n')
    print(res)
```

Please note that the variable `timestr` was created merely as storage for future use. Also, you can apply all kinds of validity checks. In my opinion, this method can't be used to parse a time input of type `14923` into `1:49:23` as lookahead is not available and there is no way of knowing whether user is going to input 12-hr time or 24-hr time. I am going for 24-hr time, which means, instead of `14923`, user will be required to enter `014923`.

Comment: Tested on Python 3.7, console. Not sure if it works in IPython/Jupyter-Notebook.

Comment: Getting "has no attribute `getwch`", also no `putwch` (or any `put...`) for Python 3.8.5, `getch` 1.0, Ubuntu 20.04 (Linux)

Comment: With a few modifications it works, though, e.g. you can just replace `putwch` with `print` and use `getche` on LInux.

Comment: @tobias_k I tested mine on windows (_yeah yeah, I know_) so I will make my answer windows only, can you add the answer for linux, since you can test as well?

Comment: I'd just add this to yours if you don't mind. You can then check if the same also works for Windows to get one that fits both.

Comment: As long as OP/other users can differentiate!

Comment: wait, I think `getche` can't be used as it will echo the character immediately

Comment: But you print the char anyway, you just have to change the order a bit.

Comment: but does that give the live feel of `:` being automatically inserted? I can't verify!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227387/discussion-between-tobias-k-and-anurag).